# Alphabetical sorting algorithm for block of rows

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, powerquery, block

My data looks like this:

```
Name      #modules      module_name    etc   ...  
Machine1     3          module1       data  
                        module2       data  
                        module3       data  
Machine2     1          module1       data  
Machine3     2          module1       data  
                        module2       data  
...
```

I want to sort this data alphabetically based on the first column (Machine names) but I want to keep the rows directly after it. So if `#modules` is 3, I want to keep those 3 rows together.

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample of the desired result.

Comment: Why don't you use table fill down options (VBA/Powerquery; there may be others) to ensure all of column A has a Name (takes the name from above)? With no blanks, a sort on Col A will preserve groupings for 3modules.

Comment: See here for how to do it with Formulas and xlBlanks.... https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html  Section you need is Using a formula to fill blank cells with value above

Answer (score 0):

In case that link disappears. There are a number of ways to essentially do a table-fill down to ensure that column A has no blank cells and therefore when sorting on it, your groups remain together.

You can use the table-fill down option in powerquery to fill the blanks will the value from above, or use VBA in a loop or use formulas with find and replace.

From the link I gave here are screenshots for fill-down with formula:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4]

Link for [VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-fill-blank-cells.htm) solution by ozgrid

```
Sub FillBlanks()

Dim rRange1 As Range, rRange2 As Range

Dim iReply As Integer

    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        MsgBox "You must select your list and include the blank cells", _

            vbInformation, "OzGrid.com"

            Exit Sub

    ElseIf Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then

        MsgBox "You must select only one column", _

            vbInformation, "OzGrid.com"

            Exit Sub

    End If



    Set rRange1 = Range(Selection.Cells(1, 1), _

        Cells(65536, Selection.Column).End(xlUp))



    On Error Resume Next

    Set rRange2 = rRange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    On Error GoTo 0



    If rRange2 Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "No blank cells Found", _

            vbInformation, "OzGrid.com"

        Exit Sub

    End If



    rRange2.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"



    iReply = MsgBox("Convert to Values", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "OzGrid.com")

    If iReply = vbYes Then rRange1 = rRange1.Value

End Sub
```

Link to powerquery example:

https://www.excelcampus.com/library/fill-down-blank-null-cells-power-query/